# jhipster 3.x java 7 support in code generation

Tags: jhipster

We are using latest jhipster and want it to use java 7 code generation. Is there any way to enforce that in jhipster command line option or any other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JHipster support for Java 7 was removed with the [2.23 version](http://jhipster.github.io/2015/10/23/jhipster-release-2.23.0.html), with [this commit](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/commit/0acf65c).
So there is no way to generate JHipster application with Java7 using the latest release.

A workaround would be to use a previous JHipster version, <2.23

Also note that java 7 has reach its end of life [since April 2015](https://java.com/en/download/faq/java_7.xml) and it's strongly recommended to start a new project with Java 8

Comment: Thank you Raphael, I will try to use older version of jHipster.